Authentication cookie not being set randomly, never shows user logged in
Do you know why sometimes my users can't login.  Basically they cookie never gets set and shows the user as logged in.  Other users seem just fine.  They go to another browser and it works but its independent of browser.  Had someone in Chrome and Edge do this.  It doesn't happen often but it does happen.
  var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        2,
        data,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),
        false,
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member, Formatting.None),
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket))
    {
        Secure = true,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
    };
    
        cookie.Domain = SportEngine.SportHost;
    
    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


If the cookie never gets set, how could the user login? The cookie may just get discarded after the browser is closed.

They try to login, but it never does.  Like the cookie in the browser either doesn't get set or something is conflicting with it.  Once you login it shows your name top right. I know they are typing it in correctly, because they mention the same thing.  The browser just reloads and never logs them in.
